# Regex has problems with poitive lookbehind

Tags: php, html, regex, optimization, lookbehind

I am currently trying to create a regex that strips unecessary quotation marks from HTML tags. The regex will be used in PHP code.

```html
<input type="image" src="/flags/en.png" alt="English" title="English" name="en" class="screen selected" />
```

converts to

```html
<input type=image src="/flags/en.png" alt=English title=English name=en class="screen selected" />
```

I have come up with this regex and replacement:

```
/(?<=<(?:[^>]+?\s)?)([\w-]+=)"([\w-]+)"(?=(?:\s[^>]+)?>)/g
$1$2
```

The problem is that the positive lookbehind does not allow quantifiers *(See http://regex101.com/ as a reference.)*.

So I thought I modify the pattern a little bit like this:

```
/(<(?:[^>]+?\s)?)([\w-]+=)"([\w-]+)"((?:\s[^>]+)?>)/g
$1$2$3$4
```

Now it's valid but it only strips one set of quotes from each tag.

How do I acomplish this?

Comment: What is the necessity?

Comment: Smaller HTML. I do this to speed up my webpage. It is not 100% necessary but I want to do it since I already started it!

Comment: this is insane microopertimisation (no idea how to spell that)

Comment: Call me insane or OCD but considering that this could easily save several KiB of code I think it is worth my time! *(My current opimizations saved me something around 10%. I did this optimization by hand and it saved an additional 2%. That makes indeed a differnece.)*

Comment: ok well lets do this properly then: rename all the files to a single letter "/flags/en.png" to just "f" then mod rewrite rules; replace ever line break\tab; you don't need those optional elements in the  input such as title at all, so strip them ...

Comment: I'm trying to **losslessly** optimize the HTML site without changing it's content. Striping elemets like the title attribute would change the page itself *(how the user sees it)* and have an impact on the usability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$pattern = '/(<(?:[^>]+?\s)?)([\w-]+=)"([\w-]+)"((?:\s[^>]+)?>)/';
$replacement = '$1$2$3$4';
$subject = '<input type="image" src="/flags/en.png" alt="English" title="English" name="en" class="screen selected" />';

while(preg_match($pattern, $subject)){
    $subject = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
}
var_dump($subject);
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. I wonder why I didn't think of this before!

Answer (score 0):

Probably won't save much, but here you go :)

```
 $string = '<input type="image" src="/flags/en.png" alt="English" title="English" name="en" class="screen selected" />'; 
 echo preg_replace('/="([a-z]+)"/i', '=$1', $string);
```

Output:

```
<input type=image src="/flags/en.png" alt=English title=English name=en class="screen selected" />
```

Comment: This can't work since there is some quoted text outside of HTML tags. These need to stay there!

Comment: Then the edited version ought to work if you want to keep it simple :)

Comment: Still there is a good chance that this might strip some quotes from outside the HTML tags...

Comment: If you were to type something such as ="blah" it would replace it with =blah, but fair enough :)

Comment: I think your solution is great in terms of simplicity but @paolo's solution is far more reliable!